# Composition with Properties

Tags: vb.net, oop

#### Edit:

To clarify, these things, screens and fields, are real-world (at least real inside a computer) things that I have no control over. The screens are views of data contained in ancient COBOL programs and the fields are places on the screens where data is located.

What I'm building is meant to replace a low-level and procedural method for interacting with these screens and fields. You might think of these objects as similar to tables and columns in a database. Right now I have to write a lot of "plumbing" to, say, update one of the fields on a particular screen, and I have to duplicate that code in order to work with a different field. What I'd like to get to is a codebase that allows me to simply set a property on a object in order to update a field, e.g. `MyScreen.MyField.Value = <new value>`.

#### Original Post:

I'm building a collection of wrapper classes that represent objects that I think would be best understood in terms of composition, as opposed to association. Briefly, I have a `screen` object that needs to contain n number of `field` objects. The fields are owned by the screen they're declared in and should not survive their screen, but must be accessible from outside the screen.

I'm struggling, though, with how to implement this relationship. My OOP knowledge tells me I should use properties to manage this. Something like:

```
Private Class MyScreen
    Inherits Screen

    Private _myField As Field
    Public ReadOnly Property MyField() As Field
        Get
            Return _myField
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

        MyBase.New()
        _myField = New Field()

    End Sub

End Class
```

However, the above seems overly verbose, given that I could just as easily do this:

```
Private Class MyScreen
    Inherits Screen

    Public Readonly MyField As Field
    
    Public Sub New()

        MyBase.New()
        MyField = New Field()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Is one or the other a better choice? Is there a third option I'm not seeing?

Comment: If this will end up in a collection and if that collection will possibly be used in a collection editor, Field is a mistake.  They are not treated the same by the UITypeEditor.  Same for databinding.  It is only verbose because you have it readonly, otherwise it could use the auto/collapsed/shorthand syntax

Comment: The problem you described is too abstract. What is the **real** problem? You should not use ANY patterns simply because they are out there. Every character in code must have sense.

Comment: @Neolisk - Thanks. I've edited the post to try to clarify things.

Comment: @Plutonix - I don't intend either the screens or the fields to be part of a collection, but I'm guessing I'm missing the point of your comment, as I don't understand what you mean about UITypeEditor.

Comment: You can have a generic wrapper, which would access its members by string. Those can be constants, so that there is less room for error. Doing as much plumbing as you are planning is an overkill to me.

Comment: `a collection...of objects` if not a collection, what lots of field objects? Arent there more than 1 field(s) per screen? What is `Field`, a class?

Comment: @Plutonix - A `Field` class defines not only where data is on a screen, but how to get from and put it there. For example, a date may be displayed as "140211". The field that returns that date knows how to convert that literal string into a actual `Date` data type and how to transform a new date into the proper format. In this way the calling application is freed from handling the work. - So, yes, there are more than 1 fields per screen, but I was hoping to just use the screen as the container. Is there a reason I should looking at putting them in a collection?

Comment: @Neolisk - Thanks for feedback. If you're interested, see my reasoning in my response to Plutonix.

Comment: So you are going to design a plumbing layer, to abstract from bad design of the old stuff? Makes sense to me. You can attempt to design a smart framework (is a buzz word today), which would determine how the value should be parsed by certain criteria. Yes you can determine yourself and code for every database table, but it may be a lot of effort. In this case you'd probably implement a custom ORM, and chances are it won't work as well, just cause old systems are not following any particular standard (from experience). Ask people, see what the ideas were put inside, see if you can generalize.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use composition rather???

You could create a `ScreenWorker` class that could be instantiated on each screen.  This `ScreenWorker` class would allow you to set parameters from the `Screen` class, allowing you to reuse the code which does the grunt work depending on the parameters you pass to it?